# Memory leak when printing 2D array

Tags: c++

I have memory leak when i print my 2D array, i looped in data from a vector into a vector called grid

Some indexes in Grid is null for example grid[8][8] is null, but grid[1][1] has a value of 3.
When i display indexes of grid with null value gives me a memory leak.

Below are my code, Any recommendations will be appreciated!

```
void populateAppendixB(vector<string> cityLocation, int **grid, int col, int row) {

    vector<int> data = appendixB_data(cityLocation);
    vector<string> appendixB_coordinates = getCoordinates(cityLocation);

    vector<int> x_value = returncolValue(appendixB_coordinates);

    vector<int> y_value = returnrowValue(appendixB_coordinates);


    //loop data into grid[][]

    for (int i = 0; i < x_value.size(); i++) {

        grid[x_value[i]][y_value[i]] = data[i];
    }   

    cout << "   ";
    //Top outer Grid

    for (int i = 0; i < col + 2; i++) {
        cout << " # ";
    }
    cout << " # ";
    cout << endl;
    //end

    //y-axis
    for (int j = row; j >= 0; --j) {
        cout << " " << j << "  #  ";

        for (int i = 0; i <= col; ++i) {

            //displaying data
            if(grid[i][j] == 0) {
                cout << "   ";
            }

            else {
                cout << grid[i][j] << "  ";
            }

        }



    //Right outer Grid
    cout << "#";
    cout << endl;
    }


    //Last row of #
    cout << "   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < col + 2; i++) {
        cout << " # ";
    }

    cout << " # ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "       ";

    //x-Axis
    for (int i = 0; i <= col; i++) {    
        cout << i << "  ";
    }

    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Easiest way to debug out of bounds violations with `vectors` is to use `.at(N)` instead of the operator `[]`, that will throw an exception when you try to make an illegal read operation. In short, try replacing all `grid[i]` with `grid.at(i)` and `grid[i][j]` with `grid.at(i).at(j)`.

Comment: I recommend not using this: `int **grid`.  Instead, use `vector<vector<int>>`, or make a class that externally represents a 2-dimensional grid, and internally uses a flat vector and calculates the index position by the 2-dimensional x,y.

Comment: Why do you think that you have a memory leak?

Comment: because when i print grid, those with null value have random numbers appearing everywhere

Comment: @user3413646 that is not a typical symptom of a memory leak. Typical symptom of memory leak is continuous increase in memory use, possibly up to the point where memory is exhausted. What you're describing sounds like undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You use `grid[x_value[i]][y_value[i]] = data[i];`, but will not fill all of the `grid` since you only fill in one value of each column of `grid` (you only do this loop: `for (int i = 0; i < x_value.size(); i++) {`). Unless the grid passed in is pre-filled in with `0`'s properly (impossible to tell given your submitted code), then this is probably undefined behavior.

Even if it is a pre-filled in 2d array, when you print the elements of `grid`, you iterate from `[0, cols]` and `[0, rows]`, which is likely not what you want (that iterates `cols+1` columns and `rows+1` rows. So, at least that last value will be accessing memory that is *probably* not valid.

As previous comments mention, it's a better idea to just use `std::vector` (e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` while using `.at(i).at(j)` to access elements which make use of C++ exceptions rather than accessing bad memory) or even `std::array` which are better at preventing and catching many issues cleanly. If you're worried about speed, it's probably not a huge deal and you can avoid copies by e.g. passing by reference, wrapping things in smart pointers if applicable, move semantics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by setting all my 2D array values to { }, then populate the grid array with the values that i want specifically.

It solves the memory leak problem but i am not sure if it is a good practice.